how can I do azure b2c passing username and password to obtain a token?
I would like for my mobile app to pass username and password and obtain a token that I can pass to web api the start transactions
I created a new application on azure b2c portal and configured and I'm not able to get tokens from postman. I'm getting an error on the response:
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow.\r\nCorrelation ID: 3e6597eb-7e23-4c51-bd77-ecb2005d325f\r\nTimestamp: 2024-04-12 14:23:36Z\r\n"

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you configure a web or SPA platform?
In those app. registrations, go to the Authentication tab, scroll down, and you'll see checkboxes for access and ID tokens required for implicit flow.
You need to check them and save them.

Yes, I did. I don't understand what's missing, I have followed every instruction to accomplish this, but something still missing.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I have found the solution, I didn't have the ROPC user flow created, with that one, everything works.
